# Can't convert numeric to date in R

Tags: r, date, datetime, numeric

I'm trying to convert some dates that are currently set as numeric to a date class. e.g. `19870101`

for example:

```
> as.Date.numeric(19870101, origin = "1970-01-01")
[1] "56417-06-28"
```

Why does this not return the correct date which should be `"1987-01-01"`. Does anyone know what I am doing wrong here, is the origin argument wrong?

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: You can do > lubridate::ymd('19870101')
[1] "1987-01-01"
>

Comment: `19870101` is not an actual number here. It is a character date that has been stored as a number. Use `as.Date.character(19870101, format = "%Y%m%d")` (you might need to adjust the format if it follows US conventions).

Answer (score 5):

```
library(lubridate)
ymd(19870101)
```

output

```
[1] "1987-01-01"
```